# Trajectory plot on phase plane for a desired initial conditions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a system of ordinary differential equations.
dx/dt=-x and
dy/dt=2x-2y

I am using StreamPlot to plot the phase portrait which gives me this
[image]

I want to pic some initial condition and study that whether the solution leads to the equilibrium point(stable one) or not. I am trying a lot but didn't getting the required result as in the picture below

[image]

I require the blue arrowed lines that are solid and pass through the equilibrium points ie (0,0) here in the pic.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only part of the work. It is hope that can help you to draw the complete picture.

Here we use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve the curves which pass through point $(a,b)$.

We select some points such as $(1,0)$,$(2,0)$,$(3,1)$ etc.

```
sols = ParametricNDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == -x[t], 
    D[y[t], t] == 2 x[t] - 2 y[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b}, {x, 
    y}, {t, -10, 10}, {a, b}];
f[a_, b_][t_] := {x[a, b][t], y[a, b][t]} /. sols;
lines1 = ParametricPlot[{f[1, 0][t], f[2, 0][t], f[3, 1][t]}, {t, -.3,
     10}, Epilog -> {Arrow[{f[1, 0][-.2], f[1, 0][-.1]}], 
     Arrow[{f[2, 0][-.2], f[2, 0][-.1]}], 
     Arrow[{f[3, 1][-.2], f[3, 1][-.1]}]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
lines2 = ParametricPlot[{f[.2, 2][t], f[.3, 2][t], 
    f[.5, 2][t]}, {t, -.3, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
lines3 = ParametricPlot[{f[-1, 0][t], f[-2, 0][t], 
    f[-3, 0][t]}, {t, -.1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green];
lines4 = ParametricPlot[{f[-.5, -2][t], f[-.8, -3][t], 
    f[-1, -3][t]}, {t, -.1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[lines1, lines2, lines3, lines4, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Move the locator to change the initial conditions.

```
   gr = StreamPlot[{-x, 2 x - 2 y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
    fun[x_, x0_, y0_] = 
      y[x] /. DSolve[{y'[x] == -2 (x - y[x])/x, y[x0] == y0}, y, x];
    Manipulate[
     Show[gr, 
      Plot[fun[x, p[[1]], p[[2]]], {x, p[[1]], 0}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}], 
      Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}]}]]
     , {{p, {2, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found another way that need not solved differential equation,only change the style of `StreamPlot` such as `StreamScale` and `StreamPoints`

```
(*pts=Tuples[Range[-2,2,.8],2];*)

pts = {{1, 0}, {1.5, 0}, {2, 0}, {.2, 2}, {.5, 2}, {1, 2}, {-2, 
    0}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-.8, -2}, {-.5, -2}, {-.2, -2}};
stream = StreamPlot[{-x, 2 x - 2 y}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   StreamScale -> {Full, Automatic, Automatic}, StreamPoints -> pts, 
   Axes -> True, Frame -> False, StreamStyle -> Blue, 
   StreamColorFunction -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
Show[Plot[x, {x, -1.8, 1.8}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  Epilog -> {Green, Text[y == x, {2, 1.8}, Left]}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 2, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.035], PlotRangePadding -> 1.1, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}], stream]
```

[image]

Comment: `StreamScale -> {{0.5, 0}, 50, .025, Automatic}`

Comment: `StreamScale -> {{.4, 0}, 50, .025, # &}`